# setPadding - bottom padding not working properly

Tags: android, padding

Guys I am extending a Progress Bar, and I am changing the height of the progress bar and setting it padding. Everything is working fine except BOTTOM padding. The issue is when i am trying following code it only showing the top padding, and no bottom padding.

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
        int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), mMaxThumbDrawable.getHeight());
    if(getWidth() > 0)
        mPixels = getWidth() / mRange;
    paddintBottom = (int)(0.8f * getHeight());
    paddintTop = (int)(0.4f * getHeight());
    setPadding(0, paddintTop, 0, paddintBottom);
}
```

XML is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.customseekbarwidget.DoubleSlider
    android:id="@+id/doubleSlider1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_bg" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the interesting part of the issue is if I specify the constant value like 44 in in place of paddintBottom like

```
setPadding(0, paddintTop, 0, 44);
```

it starts working all of sudden, but i cannot keep the value constant. any one have any idea about it.

[image]

Comment: Does the `paddingTop` work? It is in the same format as the `paddingBottom`... Are 0.4f and 0.8f hex codes?

Comment: yes padding top is working. I also added the image of the view. and those are not hex code only float values to calculate the percentage of height of the view

Comment: Is it possible when you cast it to an int that it is coming out as 0? But prior to that it is a value?

Comment: I used debugger and kept a watch on it..it is showing the value `44` at the `setPadding` statement